# Update columns in table using same table for respective IDs.

Tags: mysql, database

How can I update Opportunity_Record_Type, Opportunity_Division and Fiscal_Period from the same TABLE for respective IDs? The PK is Opportunity_ID.

```
+--------------------+-------------------------+----------------------+---------------+-----------------------+--------------------------+
| Opportunity_ID     | Opportunity_Record_Type | Opportunity_Division | Fiscal_Period | Script_Execution_Week | Script_Execution_Quarter |
+--------------------+-------------------------+----------------------+---------------+-----------------------+--------------------------+
| LKASDJKLkasdkl23k4 | NULL                    | NULL                 | NULL          | 2017-21               | 2017-Q2                  |
| LKASDJKLkasdkl23k4 | NULL                    | NULL                 | NULL          | 2017-22               | 2017-Q2                  |
| LKASDJKLkasdkl23k4 | NULL                    | NULL                 | NULL          | 2017-23               | 2017-Q2                  |
| LKASDJKLkasdkl23k4 | NULL                    | NULL                 | NULL          | 2017-24               | 2017-Q2                  |
| LKASDJKLkasdkl23k4 | NULL                    | NULL                 | NULL          | 2017-25               | 2017-Q2                  |
| LKASDJKLkasdkl23k4 | Services                | SBS                  | 2017-Q2       | 2017-26               | 2017-Q3                  |
| LKASDJKLkasdkl23k4 | Services                | SBS                  | 2017-Q2       | 2017-27               | 2017-Q3                  |
| LKASDJKLkasdkl23k4 | Services                | SBS                  | 2017-Q2       | 2017-28               | 2017-Q3                  |
| LKASDJKLkasdkl23k4 | NULL                    | NULL                 | NULL          | 2017-7                | 2017-Q1                  |
| LKASDJKLkasdkl23k4 | NULL                    | NULL                 | NULL          | 2017-8                | 2017-Q1                  |
| LKASDJKLkasdkl23k4 | NULL                    | NULL                 | NULL          | 2017-9                | 2017-Q1                  |
| SDFSDKLJ2ELKMLKASM | NULL                    | NULL                 | NULL          | 2017-20               | 2017-Q2                  |
| SDFSDKLJ2ELKMLKASM | NULL                    | NULL                 | NULL          | 2017-21               | 2017-Q2                  |
| SDFSDKLJ2ELKMLKASM | NULL                    | NULL                 | NULL          | 2017-22               | 2017-Q2                  |
| SDFSDKLJ2ELKMLKASM | NULL                    | NULL                 | NULL          | 2017-23               | 2017-Q2                  |
| SDFSDKLJ2ELKMLKASM | NULL                    | NULL                 | NULL          | 2017-24               | 2017-Q2                  |
| SDFSDKLJ2ELKMLKASM | NULL                    | NULL                 | NULL          | 2017-25               | 2017-Q2                  |
| SDFSDKLJ2ELKMLKASM | Mobile                  | Mobile               | 2017-Q2       | 2017-26               | 2017-Q3                  |
| SDFSDKLJ2ELKMLKASM | Mobile                  | Mobile               | 2017-Q2       | 2017-27               | 2017-Q3                  |
| SDFSDKLJ2ELKMLKASM | Mobile                  | Mobile               | 2017-Q2       | 2017-28               | 2017-Q3                  |
+--------------------+-------------------------+----------------------+---------------+-----------------------+--------------------------+
```

Comment: You know, for the purposes of the question, the opportunity_id could be something simpler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```sql
UPDATE table1 t JOIN (
  SELECT Opportunity_ID, Opportunity_Record_Type, Opportunity_Division, Fiscal_Period
    FROM table1
   WHERE Opportunity_Record_Type IS NOT NULL
     AND Opportunity_Division IS NOT NULL
     AND Fiscal_Period IS NOT NULL
   GROUP BY Opportunity_ID, Opportunity_Record_Type, Opportunity_Division, Fiscal_Period
  ) q
    ON t.Opportunity_ID = q.Opportunity_ID
   SET t.Opportunity_Record_Type = q.Opportunity_Record_Type,
       t.Opportunity_Division = q.Opportunity_Division,
       t.Fiscal_Period = q.Fiscal_Period
 WHERE t.Opportunity_Record_Type IS NULL
    OR t.Opportunity_Division IS NULL
    OR t.Fiscal_Period IS NULL
```

Here is a [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=fc861fc6e3572206281946721223d580) demo

Answer (score 0):

Updated based on your comments. I believe you need an inner join to achieve what you are trying to do. Please place your table name everywhere that I wrote 'YourTableName'. Your going to join on 3 different sub queries which will pull the distinct value for the column for that particular ID.

```
UPDATE test 
SET Opportunity_Record_Type = join1.Opportunity_Record_Type,
    Opportunity_Division = join2.Opportunity_Division, 
    Fiscal_Period = join3.Fiscal_Period 
FROM 'YourTableName' test
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT Opportunity_ID, Opportunity_Record_Type 
        FROM 'YourTableName' 
        WHERE Opportunity_Record_Type IS NOT NULL) join1 ON join1.Opportunity_ID = test.Opportunity_ID
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT Opportunity_ID, Opportunity_Division 
        FROM 'YourTableName'
        WHERE Opportunity_Division IS NOT NULL) join2 ON join2.Opportunity_ID = test.Opportunity_ID
    INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Opportunity_ID, Fiscal_Period 
        FROM 'YourTableName' 
        WHERE Fiscal_Period IS NOT NULL) join3 ON join3.Opportunity_ID = test.Opportunity_ID
```

Comment: No sir. For each ID, I want to update their 3 specified columns which are NULL with populated values for same ID. For example if you take this ID 'LKASDJKLkasdkl23k4', I want to update Opportunity_Record_Type, Opportunity_Division and Fiscal_Period with values from 2017-26 week.

Comment: Updated my answer based on your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for you. It is best obtained by inserting, and when there is a duplicate key update the values. I filled it with dummy data because I don't know what valid inputs are for you.

```
INSERT INTO table (Opportunity_ID,Opportunity_Record_Type,Opportunity_Division,Fiscal_Period) 
VALUES (PK,1,1,1),
       (PK,1,1,1),
       (PK,1,1,1),
       (PK,1,1,1)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Opportunity_Record_Type=1,Opportunity_Division=1,...;
```